# For Python, how to sort and lump elements in a fixed-sized list

Tags: python, list, sorting, numpy

Sorry if this is a trivial question. If I have a list:

```
inputlist = [(0,0), (_,_), (_,_), (0,0), (0,0), (_,_), (0,0)]
```

What is an efficient way to sort it so that all the non-zero elements get lumped to the left (in any order):

```
sortlist = [(_,_), (_,_), (_,_), (0,0), (0,0), (0,0), (0,0)]
```

Comment: Are you using the variable _ on purpose, or it's just a placeholder?  This variable does some magic things in python ..

Comment: Just a placeholder. Sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a key that returns a lower for anything non-zero, like `-1` vs. `0`:

```
sorted(inputlist, key=lambda t: -1 if t != (0, 0) else 0)
```

This can be simplified to:

```
sorted(inputlist, key=lambda t: t == (0, 0))
```

since `False` is sorted before `True`

Demo:

```
>>> import random
>>> r = lambda: random.randint(1, 10)
>>> inputlist = [(0,0), (r(),r()), (r(),r()), (0,0), (0,0), (r(),r()), (0,0)]
>>> sorted(inputlist, key=lambda t: t == (0, 0))
[(4, 5), (3, 2), (3, 3), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0), (0, 0)]
```

All non-zero tuples are left in their original order, just moved to the front of the output list.

Answer (score 3):

```
sorted(my_list, key=(0,0).__eq__)
```